# Origin of Messianic Term "Son of David"

Tags: matthew, christology, messiah

I know that Matthew uses the phrase the "Son of David" as a designation for the Messiah frequently in his gospel.  I am wondering where the phrase originated.

The Hebrew Bible contains references to a Messiah who will rule on the throne of David (Isaiah 9:6) and to a future restoration of the House of David (Amos 9:11) and even to one "called to be ruler" in Israel coming from Bethlehem, the birthplace of David (Micah 5:2).

However I cannot find the phrase "Son of David" anywhere in the Hebrew Bible as a designation of the Messiah.  Did that phrase originate in the 1st century with the gospel writers or was it present in any Jewish apocalyptic literature prior to the first century (e.g. Enoch, Jubilees, Sibylline Oracles, etc.).

Comment: It isn't a terribly idiomatic term. Are you looking for the *first* occurrence of "the descendant of David" as applied to the Messiah? The term itself was applied to Solomon but again, it is simply descriptive. Does 2 Samuel 7 clarify anything for you?

Comment: There is a rich scholarly bibliography on this: see (for starters): Jack Dean Kingsbury's [article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3265574) (1976); Dennis Duling's [article](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/014610799202200302) (1992); Lidija Novakovic's [book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RWVhXZhY0qgC&printsec=frontcover) (2003); Yigal Levin's [article](https://www.academia.edu/239076/) (2006). Etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks David.  No, 2 Samuel 7:14, Isiah 9:6-7, Micah 5:2, etc. don't provide what I am looking for.  I am looking for the use of the term "Son of David" as a Messianic title in the way that the author of Matthew's gospel used it.  Thanks for the articles.  I will take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that God promised that David's lineage would rule Israel. This covenant was understood as resolute even by the second century BC:

> **Sirach 45.25**
>
> Just as a covenant was established with David son of Jesse of the tribe of Judah, that the king’s heritage passes only from son to son, so the heritage of Aaron is for his descendants alone.

> **1 Maccabees 2.57**
>
> David, because he was merciful, inherited the throne of the kingdom forever.

This belief was predicated on the prophets, who anticipated a future king who would rule Israel and Judah would be descended from David. Sometimes this genealogical relationship is inferred by context; the future king is identified as 'David' by name, or the king is identified as fulfilling the aforementioned covenant that God would preserve David's dynasty (his 'house', 'tent', or 'throne').

> **Hosea 3.5**
>
> Afterward the Israelites shall return and seek Yahweh their God, and David their king; they shall come in awe to Yahweh and to his goodness in the latter days.

> **Amos 9.11**
>
> On that day I will raise up the booth of David that is fallen, and repair its breaches, and raise up its ruins, and rebuild it as in the days of old

> **Isaiah 11.1,10**
>
> A shoot shall come out from the stock of Jesse [David's father], and a branch shall grow out of his roots. [...] On that day the root of Jesse shall stand as a signal to the peoples; the nations shall inquire of him, and his dwelling shall be glorious.

> **Isaiah 16.5**
>
> then a throne shall be established in steadfast love in the tent of David, and on it shall sit in faithfulness a ruler who seeks justice and is swift to do what is right.

> **Jeremiah 23.5**
>
> The days are surely coming, says Yahweh, when I will raise up for David a righteous branch, and he shall reign as king and deal wisely, and shall execute justice and righteousness in the land.

> **Ezekiel 34.24**
>
> And I, Yahweh, will be their God, and my servant David shall be prince among them; I, Yahweh, have spoken.

> **Zechariah 12.8**
>
> On that day Yahweh will shield the inhabitants of Jerusalem so that the feeblest among them on that day shall be like David, and the house of David shall be like God, like the angel of the Lord, at their head.

The clearest example in the prophets that this relationship is understood as a literal genealogical one, and not a metaphoric kinship, is Jeremiah 33:

> **Jeremiah 33.14-26**
>
> The days are surely coming, says Yahweh, when I will fulfill the promise I made to the house of Israel and the house of Judah. In those days and at that time I will cause a righteous branch to spring up for David; and he shall execute justice and righteousness in the land. [...] For thus says Yahweh: David shall never lack a man to sit on the throne of the house of Israel [...] If any of you could break my covenant with the day and my covenant with the night [...] only then could my covenant with my servant David be broken, so that he would not have a son to reign on his throne [...] Only if I had not established my covenant with day and night and the ordinances of heaven and earth, would I reject the offspring of Jacob and of my servant David and not choose any of his descendants as rulers

Israel would always have a king, and the king would always be descended from David: a son of David.

The precise phrase 'son of David' is used only six times in the Hebrew bible, but they all come from post-exilic books: Chronicles, Proverbs, and Ecclesiastes. Of the six instances, five are for Solomon, three of which are accompanied by the title 'king of Israel' or 'king in Jerusalem'.

By the first century BC, the exact phrase, though still associated with Solomon, had been tied into the messianic expectations that grew out of the earlier prophetic literature.

> **Psalms of Solomon 17.4,21**
>
> You, O Lord, you chose David king over Israel, and you swore to him concerning his offspring forever, that his palace would never fail before you. [...] See, O Lord, and raise up for them their king, the son of David, at the time which you chose, O God, to rule over Israel your servant.

The passage continues with allusions to Psalm 2, as well as the prophetic texts given above. The Psalm of Solomon even identifies this son of David as 'the messiah' in verse 32.

---

### Conclusion

The Book of Chronicles was probably written in the fourth century BC. Ecclesiastes and Proverbs are often dated around the same period or a little later. Although the phrase 'son of David' in these books is connected only to Solomon, it would seem that the phrase was beginning to take on a particular idiomatic meaning essentially synonymous to 'king of Israel'.

By the first century BC, the phrase had become associated with 'the messiah' in particular.

Comment: Thanks Mark Edward, that is a very thorough answer.  It looks like the Psalms of Solomon 17 contains what I am looking for.  I wanted to find where the term "Son of David" became a title for the Messiah.  I had searched the Hebrew Bible and found the verses that you mentioned, but most of them applied to Solomon or just to the idea that David's sons would continue to reign in Judah.

Comment: I think Mark has nailed it. See the full text of Ps of Sol 17 in [English](http://wesley.nnu.edu/sermons-essays-books/noncanonical-literature/noncanonical-literature-ot-pseudepigrapha/the-psalms-of-solomon/) (scroll a long way down!), and also [some reliable info on this text](http://www.earlyjewishwritings.com/psalmssolomon.html). The older work of Dalman is still cited: see his [identification of Ps Sol 17:23\[21\]](https://archive.org/stream/wordsofjesus00dalmuoft#page/n331/mode/2up) as the first messianic use of the formula "Son of David". If it was my Q, this A would have a green tick. :)

Comment: P.s. @BillBenninghoff see also the much more recent discussion of Novenson, *Grammar of Messianism* (OUP, 2017) who discusses this text (Ps Sol 17) and formula (no reference to Dalman) [on p. 56f.](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VPdKDgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA209&pg=PA56#v=onepage&q&f=false). There are other mentions of the formula in that book which you might find interesting. (You might find the whole book interesting!)

Comment: Thanks David - I am new to this so I didn't know about the "green tick."  I just added it.  Thanks for the reference to Novenson.

Answer (score 0):

In all likelihood, this stems from a verse in Psalm 132 and other verses like it: "The LORD hath sworn in truth unto David; he will not turn from it; **Of the fruit of thy body will I set upon thy throne.**" (Ps 132:11).

This references a prophecy made to David: "When your days are complete and you lie down with your fathers, I will raise up your descendant after you, who will come forth from you, and I will establish his kingdom. “He shall build a house for My name, and **I will establish the throne of his kingdom forever**"(1 Sam 7:12-13).

For this reason, Jews and Christians believe the Messiah would be a descendant of David's.

Comment: Thanks David Hockley but that's not what I am looking for.  I am looking for the use of the term "Son of David" as a Title of the Messiah.  I have searched the Hebrew Bible but have not found it so I was wondering if it appears anywhere in the Intertestamental literature such as Enoch, Jubiliees, Sibylline Oracles, DSS, etc.